# Monochromatic colors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors

In Matlab how can I make a function monochromatic orange (like the kind where it says "Ask Question" on the right side of the screen) ?

Comment: Functions are mathematical abstractions, they can't have colour. Do you want a line made orange? Or are you attempting to make a GUI object orange?

Answer (score 0):

Not suite sure if this what you mean, but

Click `File` -> `Preferences` then

1. Choosing the `Colors` option on the left pane lets you set desktop and syntax highlighting colours.
2. Choosing `Editor/Debugger` -> `Display` lets you choose the colour of highlighted cells.

stackoverflow orange is `R: 255, G: 153, B: 0` or `H: 36, S: 100, V: 100`.